# What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric pentadiagonal Toeplitz matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, toeplitz-matrices

\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha & \beta & \gamma  & \dots & 0  & 0      & 0 \\
        \beta & \alpha & \beta  & \dots & 0  & 0      & 0 \\
  \gamma  & \beta & \alpha & \dots & 0  & 0      & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \alpha & \beta      & \gamma \\
  0      & 0      & 0  & \dots & \beta & \alpha & \beta \\
        0      & 0      & 0  & \dots & \gamma & \beta  & \alpha
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

For symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix ($\gamma=0$), we have a closed-form solution.

Is there a closed-form solution for the symmetric pentadiagonal toeplitz matrix?

Comment: Are you also intending that the matrix be symmetric?

Comment: Compute the eigenvalues of a single block and multiply them by the number of the blocks.

Comment: $A-\lambda I$ will also be of this form, with $\alpha$ replaced by $\alpha-\lambda$.  If you let $D_n$ be the determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix of this form, you should be able to get a linear recurrence relation for $D_n$ in terms of the 3 previous terms.

Comment: Yes, it's symmetric. I wonder if there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.html

Comment: Toeplitz matrices are not easily diagonalized (not analytically at least). Instead circulant matrices can be diagonalized by Fourier transform. If you are interested in the behavior for large $N$ (=matrix dimension) than this is the way to go. You can also look at Szego's theorem.

Comment: ... However I didn't realize that your matrix has a very special form. So indeed an analytical expression may be possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are no closed-form formulas in general. You can, for example, read https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05243 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10551

Answer (score 0):

No, but it is possible to derive a generating function that gives the sum of the rows as the matrix is raised to some power $y$, for the $n \times n$ matrix. Summing the first $y$ values of the function (with coefficients in the series having the form $a_y z^y$ ) gives the sum. The pentadiagonal has an analytic solution because the cubic is solvable.